# Операторы if: больше, но меньше

Tags: операторы, php

Подскажите как мне составить оператор. Мне нужно, чтобы к примеру с 10 часов утра до 23 выполнялось что то... а в остальное время ну я думаю это будет `else`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
date('H:i:s'); // получаете текущее время
```

- **H** - Часы в 24-часовом формате с ведущим нулём
- **i** - Минуты с ведущим нулём
- **s** - Секунды с ведущим нулём

Теперь сравниваете:

```
$current_time = date('H:i:s');
if($current_time >= '10:00:00' && $current_time < '23:00:00'){
    echo 'Welcome!';
} else {
    echo 'We have a break!';
}
```

Comment: как насчет между 23:00 и 01:00(след сутки) ? :)

Comment: А какая разница? Берется то текущее время.

    $current_time >= '23:00:00' || $current_time < '01:00:00'

Меня как раз смущает вообще подобного рода проверка. Что будет, если время будет не целое число часов? Например, 10:25?

Comment: @Johny, не пойму что вас смущает. Будет ли корректно сравнивать?

    echo '10:00:00' < '10:25:00'; // true 
    echo '23:00:00' > '10:25:00'; // true

В конце концов, можно даты перевести в timestamp и сравнивать его:

    $time_start = strtotime(date('d-m-Y').' 10:00:00'); // от
    $time_finish = strtotime(date('d-m-Y').' 23:00:00'); // до
    $current_time = strtotime(date('d-m-Y H:i:s')); // текущее
    // или то же самое с помощью класса DateTime